# Specify spring config file from default config file

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm building a war package which will be deployed into a web container using spring boot. And I want to put the spring boot config file outside the war file. My idea is to put the file location in System Property and specify it from spring boot's default config file in directory resources, something like this:

```
spring.config.additional-location: ${encryption.home}/
```

or

```
spring.config.location: ${encryption.home}/
```

But neither works, seems it doesn't load the external config file. How can I do this? Or whether there's another approach for me to put spring boot config file (not in classpath) outside a WAR file.

Comment: Have you exported the `encryption.home` env variable before surring the app? You first need to `export ENCRYPTION_HOME=file:/path/to/configfile` and then run `java -jar projectName.war`

Comment: I'm building a war file and it will be deployed into a web container. And I already set the system property `encryption.home` in that container.

Comment: Can you try setting `ENCRYPTION_HOME` instead of `encryption.home` and perhaps set the env var instead os sys prop? Also try running a simple application which grabs value from `@Value("${enc.home}")` and logs into console, to confirm whether the application is getting the value or not.

Comment: Tried with name `ENCRYPTION_HOME`, got the same problem. And for os sys prop, even it worked, it'd be inappropriate in my situation, policy stuff. App can grab the value using @Value.

Comment: That's strange, if you are able to read the values then it should work. Not sure, but could be the problem with the key name itself. You can remove the `${encryption.home}/` from the property file and directly set the `spring.config.location` in env or sys var.

Comment: The thing is there are more than one app on that container, each use different home dir, but in one domain. So I need to set one prop for each app, like APP1_HOME, APP2_HOME, and each app use different one.